# Why doesn't this compile? (VC++ 2015, #pragma omp flush)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openmp

Here's a minimal case. Compile with "/openmp" on Visual C++ 2015.

```
#include <vector>
void main()
{
    bool foo = false;
    #pragma omp flush (foo)
    std::vector<int> bar;
}
```

I get:

```
C2146   syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'bar'
C2275   'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>' : illegal use of this type as an expression
C2065   'bar' : undeclared identifier
```

If I comment out the `#pragma`, the error goes away.

If I replace `std::vector` with `int`, the error goes away.

If I put a `;` on a line by itself below the `#pragma`, the error goes away.

Comment: Don't you need to include `omp.h` to use the pragmas? Don't have VS with me right now, can check it tomorrow morning :-)

Comment: I copy pasted it into my VS2015 and it compiled and ran fine.

Comment: @triple_r Just added `#include <omp.h>`, the error is still there.

Comment: @JamesRoot did you use the "/openmp" option? (The error also goes away if compiled without OpenMP support.)

Comment: I don't suppose you've got some weirdness due to non-CRLF line endings in your source?  Have you tried creating a fresh project with OpenMP enabled, then pasting in a copy of your source from StackOverflow?

Comment: @user3667352 Hm you're right, adding "/openmp" gave me the same errors.

Comment: Compiles fine for me. I turned on openmp support under Config Props\C++\Lang Support. Am using VS2013 though

Comment: I also have access to VS2013, so I copied and pasted into a new VS2013 project and turned on OpenMP, and it compiled fine.

Comment: Then imported the VS2013 solution into VS2015, which upgraded it, and when compiled, got the same errors as above. So perhaps time to report a compiler bug.

Comment: @JamesRoot thanks for the confirmation that it's not just me.

Comment: Confirmed here, too. I think it's a bug, worth reporting. FWIW the code will compile if you enclose the `#pragma omp flush` directive in `{}` braces on separate lines.

Comment: This isn't the only compiler with this type of bug. At least two compilers choke on #pragma omp barrier after a case statement if not enclosed by brackets.

Comment: Microsoft just don't care about OpenMP. Their compiler is stuck at the 10+ years old version 2.0 of the specification and they have neither plans to upgrade it nor to support it further. You should switch to a different compiler (GCC, Intel, whatever) if you'd like to develop OpenMP applications.

Answer (score 1):

The concise answer to the question "Why doesn't this compile?" is "it's a compiler bug".  The bug report at:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/2420614
has been closed as "fixed".... "this item has been fixed in the current or upcoming version of this product [Visual Studio 2015]".

Comment: This builds on MSVC 2015 Update 3. So, I'm not sure your answer is correct. Maybe you need to verify that you're using the latest patched version?

Comment: @Mikhail, I can't see how anything you've written invalidates the answer.